A conditional logistic model vs Time discrete Survival model
I was thinking that there is a distinction between a conditional logistic model and Cox proportional hazards when time has a discrete format. However, according to coxph {survival} in R and the following publication, it seems they consider these two methods equivalent. I would be thankful if I could have your clarification regarding this.
Lachin, JM Sample Size Evaluation for a Multiply Matched Case-Control Study Using the Score
Test From a **Conditional Logistic (Discrete Cox PH)** Regression Model. Stat Med. 2008 

Also in survival package in R, it is mentioned that
Using the "exact partial likelihood" approach the Cox partial likelihood is equivalent to that for
matched logistic regression. (The clogit function uses the coxph code to do the fit.) It is technically appropriate when the time scale is discrete and has only a few unique values, and some
packages refer to this as the "discrete" option. There is also an "exact marginal likelihood" due to
Prentice which is not implemented here.


I think that the question linked as a duplicate is essentially the same as yours. The code might be the same but the applications in practice are quite different. If that other question doesn't address all of your concerns, please edit this question to specify what remains unclear to you.
